# Clear the input buffer

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the press any key to continue function by using `kbhit`, however, after the user presses a key for example `a`, it will appear in the input buffer the next time I ask the user to input a value. How do you clear the input buffer?

my code for press any button to continue is below.

```
void
press_any_key(void)
{
  int b=0;
  while (b==0) 
  {
    b=kbhit();
  }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`I'm trying to implement the press any key to continue function by using kbhit` taking this statement as a need to wait for user keyboard input to continue the program execution the below code does the job,

```
void press_any_key(void)
{
   while(1)
   {
      if(kbhit())
      ch  = getch();
      printf("You passed %c\n", ch);
   }
}
```

Note: the above snippet doesn't try to clear the input buffer. However `kbhit()` is non standard instead the right way is to read a character from `stdin` is using `fgetc`.